# Why are travel ban from North Korea to the USA?

Tags: usa, tourist-visas

Since some days are travel ban to the USA from non muslim coutry Venezuela and North-Korea.
My quetion ist why North-Korea?
The travelers from North-Korea must be by Zero, or?

Edit: My main question was about travelers from North-Korea to the USA. But you all are right, it is a politic question, so please closed this question. Sorry about.

Comment: An interesting question, but maybe more suited to Politics.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more suitable for politics.SE, which has similar questions about previous travel bans or restrictions. There isn't a strong enough claim for this question being useful for travellers.

Comment: You are right it is better on Politics.SE. I'am so sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you missed the North Korean [warmongering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea%E2%80%93United_States_relations#Trump_and_UN_member_states_on_North_Korea.27s_threats)

This is **exactly** why

> (d)  North Korea.
>
> (i)   North Korea does not cooperate with the United States Government in any respect and fails to satisfy all information-sharing requirements.
>
> (ii)  The entry into the United States of nationals of North Korea as
> immigrants and nonimmigrants is hereby suspended.

Source: [White House](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2017/09/24/enhancing-vetting-capabilities-and-processes-detecting-attempted-entry)